Docker Desktop .gitconfig path sharing crashes application
Upon running an application, I get the below error:
The path /Users/my-user/.gitconfig is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.

I've already added a path to 'File Sharing' in 'Resources' in the Docker Desktop, that path being the path to the application I'm trying to run. Sharing that path works just fine.
However, adding the above path crashes the engine and causes Docker Desktop to repeatedly quit. Below is the exact error:
Invalid virtual machine configuration. 
A directory sharing device configuration is invalid.

I don't know why it's being considered invalid, since the file exists and the application needs the path to that file to run
These are the contents of that .gitconfig file:
[user]
        name = my name
        email = myname@company.com
[pull]
        rebase = true

